# Invocation exception in executing graphviz

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I tried to plot a graph of decision tree in jupyter notebook and everytime I executed got an error. I tried to fix it by reinstalling anaconda and pydotplus using conda, and also installing graphviz externally from the web but none could help.

`from IPython.display import Image`

`Image(filename="image/a.jpg.jpg", width=200, height= 400)`

this also worked well ...couldn't find the problem....
since I tried to set the environment variables for graphviz and my c/jatin directory as it showed couldn't recognize as external or internal command

This is the code:

[image: it's the code]

This is the exception:

[image: it's the exception]

Comment: could you please include your code as text instead of posting a photo of it?

Answer (score 0):

M sorry for posting it as picture ...
I tried reinstalling anaconda nd am error dat occured again n again which i ignored was ....it poped with a message" your destination folder contains 1 space nd  some conda packages would have problem" something of this kind ...It was C:/users/Jatin Aditya/anaconda3........den i reinstalled windows 10 naming only jatin ......now wen it was installed in C:/users/jatin .....nothing poped nd it was normally installed nd in jupyter termi al i installed pydotplus ...nd my code was working ..
Thank you for the concern